# How do I use blur in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

I have the following code:

```
 $(function() {
    $('.type_choice_textarea').on('focus', function() {
        $(this).css("height", "150px");
    });
    if ($('.type_choice_textarea').val().length == 0) {
        $('.type_choice_textarea').on('blur', function() {
            $(this).css("height", "30px");
        });
    }
});
```

but `blur` does not work. How do I use `if` in `blur`?

Comment: Move `if` condition inside the `blur` event handler. i.e. `$('.type_choice_textarea').on('blur', function () {
 if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
  $(this).css("height", "30px");
 }
});
`

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, depends on what you want it to do :)

Comment: *«how to use if in blur?»* ... Well use it **in** !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write you if condition within blur event handler

```
 $(function() {
    let elem = '.type_choice_textarea';

    $(elem).on('focus', function() {
        $(this).css("height", "150px");
    });

    $(elem).on('blur', function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {            
        $(this).css("height", "30px");
      }
    });
});
```